# How to Configure Airflow Celery executor with redis sentinel?

Tags: redis, celery, airflow, master-slave, sentinel

Redis sentinel setup is done.

what all changes i have to do to point my celery backend to redis-sentinel?
i am using redis as a broker for celery executor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example in the [Configuration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#configuration) section of the [Using Redis](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html) page in the Celery documentation.

From that page:

```
app.conf.broker_url = 'sentinel://localhost:26379;sentinel://localhost:26380;sentinel://localhost:26381'
app.conf.broker_transport_options = { 'master_name': "cluster1" }
```